# Transfer data from ViewModel to TemplatedControl Avalonia

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have UserControl "SetAge." In the View part of this UserControl, I have a TemplatedControl "HorizontalSpinner" in which the NumericValue property is defined. In ViewModel "SetAgeViewModel" I change the Value property, which is double, hoping that the NumericValue in "HorizontalSpinner" will also change, but this does not happen. What could be the problem?

SetAge.axaml

```
<local:VerticalSpinnerWithButtons Grid.Row="1" NumericValue="{Binding Value}" NumericIncrement="1" NumericMinimum="0" NumericMaximum="100"/>
```

SetAgeViewModel.cs

```
private double _value;
public double Value
{
      get => _value;
      set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _value, value);
}
```

HorizontalSpinner.axaml

```
<NumericUpDown Height="52" Width="66" Grid.Column="3" Value="{TemplateBinding NumericValue}" Increment="{TemplateBinding NumericIncrement}" Minimum="0" IsReadOnly="True" IsHitTestVisible="False" Foreground="#006FFF" Background="Black" BorderBrush="#006FFF" CornerRadius="10" FontSize="18" Maximum="100" ShowButtonSpinner="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" >
```

HorizontalSpinner.cs

```
public static readonly StyledProperty<double> NumericValueProperty = AvaloniaProperty.Register<VerticalSpinnerWithButtons, double>(nameof(NumericValue), 0);

public double NumericValue
{
     get => GetValue(NumericValueProperty);
     set => SetValue(NumericValueProperty, value);
}
```

I tried to change StyledProperty to DirectProperty, but it didn't help. At the same time, the transmission of string (instead of double) works perfectly.